# Is there a way to embed an Applet into an HTML5 document that is supported by all browsers?

Tags: java, html, applet

I want to have my applet in my HTML5 web page and available to all browsers, but how do I do this?

Comment: what do you want this applet to achieve?

Comment: I want to have the applet be card game

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_applet.asp), the `<applet>` tag is not supported on HTML5, which I assume BlueJ uses.